# How do I query for a key in an embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB query, I can find all vendors with an certain id in position 0 using the following query:

```
db.vendor.find({"agent_id.0":"54110be4763f4a04208b47ab"},{name:1})
```

How do I query for all vendors with a given id at any position under agent_id?  i.e. `agent_id.0` or `agent_id.1` through `agent_id.n`.

Comment: Can you show us a sample document schema?

Comment: Are you looking for a where clause like this? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if ID is in the `agent_id` array:

```
db.vendor.find({agent_id: {$in: ["54110be4763f4a04208b47ab"]}})
```

If I understood correctly.

Comment: perfect!  Thanks!  If you have the patience, how would I then delete these documents in the `vendor` collection?

Comment: @dwstein You can do with `remove` using the same query, i.e. `db.vendor.remove({agent_id: {$in: ["54110be4763f4a04208b47ab"]}})`.

Comment: You can also do `db.vendor.find({ "agent_id": "54110be4763f4a04208b47ab" }) `